# Tango mapper dies after system upgrade

Tags: google-project-tango

Today I accidentally upgrade the Yellowstone that I was working on and after the system upgrade, the TangoMapper is not working any more. The app can be launched and you can still choose the specifications for your data collection such as "Enable recording" and "Enable depth", but when you click Live Sensor Data -> [VGA+Depth], only red window will shows up at the place where it use to show the camera recording, and the depth measurement is not shown at all on the right. I wonder has anybody encountered this situation before? I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Da, You might have a out dated apk. However, Tango Mapper is a Tango internal tool. I wonder how did you get it.. Even though you have the apk, it won't get updated unless you have internal access to Tango team..